# Google Home/Assistant - Can I enable interaction with a device during and as part of a Google Assistant Smart Speaker conversation?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-home

I suppose what I'm really asking is second screening using Google Assistant via Home Speaker.

Is it possible to build an action that enables the system to send visual elements (not sure what to call them) to the user's phone while they are still having a conversation using the Home Smart Speaker. These visual elements may or may not allow for interaction.

For instance - If the user is in an action that allows him or her to search for movies and movie times via voice, then see a shortlist of these movie times shown somehow on the phone (responsive web? an app? or perhaps in the Google Home App? or even a link in the google home app that links out to a responsive web page) and then the user can interact with this by tapping on the device (such as select a movie and time) then able to carry on with the conversation. For instance to confirm payment for the tickets using google pay via voice.

Is this possible please? If so, where can I see documentation or further evidence?

If this isn't possible, what do you think would be the next best thing?

Thanks very much,
Sentry1

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is adding [rich responses](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/responses#rich_responses) to your action. These allow you to add visual elements to a conversational action. However, you cannot currently link to the web from smart displays.

If you are specifically looking to build an action that can allow users to purchase something, you'll need to review the docs on [transactions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/transactions). You probably want to look at the transactions with Google Pay or with merchant-managed payments.